# Why glBufferSubData need to wait until the VBO is not used by glDrawElements?

Tags: opengl

In OpenGL Insights, it says that "OpenGL driver has to wait because VBO is used
by glDrawElements from previous frame".

That confused me a lot.
As I know, glBufferSubData will copy the data to temporary memory, and then transfer to GPU later.

So why the driver still need to wait? it can just append the Transfer command to the command queue, delaying transfering the data to GPU until the glDrawElements is finished, right?

----- ADDED --------------------------------------------------------------------------

In OpenGL Insights, it says:

http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-AsynchronousBufferTransfers.pdf (Page 397)

> However, when using glBufferSubData or glMapBuffer[Range], nothing in
>   the API itself prevents us from modifying data that are currently used
>   by the device for rendering the previous frame, as shown in Figure
>   28.3. **Drivers have to avoid this problem by blocking the function until the desired data are not used anymore: this is called an
>   implicit synchronization.**

And also in "Beyond Porting" by Valve & NVIDIA, it says:

http://media.steampowered.com/apps/steamdevdays/slides/beyondporting.pdf

> MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED
>
> - Avoids an application-GPU sync point (a CPU-GPU
>     sync point)
> - But causes the Client and Server threads to serialize
>
>   - This
>       forces all pending work in the server thread to complete
>   - It’s quite
>       expensive (almost always needs to be avoided)

Both of them pointed out that glBufferSubData/glMapBuffer will block the application thread, not just the driver thread.

Why is it?

Comment: That is what this "waiting" is all about. It delays the transfer until after the old command finishes.

Comment: It means exactly that. The driver can't start transfering and overwriting the buffer in GPU memory with the new content because it's being currently used. Just avoid this kind of behaviours. The same book should suggest a couple of alternatives: use a roundrobin set of buffers, buffer orphaning, `ARB_buffer_storage`...

Comment: Thank you all, I've updated the question, please check it again.

Comment: I posted an answer below that explains it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no rule saying that the driver has to wait. It needs to ensure that buffer content is not modified before draw calls using the old content have finished executing. And it needs to consume the data that the caller passed in before the `glBufferSubData()` call returns. As long as the resulting behavior is correct, any implementation in the driver is fair game.

Let's illustrate the problem with a typical pseudo-call sequence, labelling the calls for later explanation:

```
(1) glBindBuffer(buf)
(2) glBufferSubData(dataA)
(3) glDraw()
(4) glBufferSubData(dataB)
(5) glDraw()
```

The constraints in play are:

- The data pointed to by `dataA` cannot be accessed by the driver after call (2) returns. The OpenGL specs allow the caller to do anything it wants with the data after the call returns, so it needs to be consumed by the driver before the call returns.
- The data pointed to by `dataB` cannot be accessed by the driver after call (4) returns.
- The draw command resulting from call (3) needs to be executed while the content of `buf` is `dataA`.
- The draw command resulting from call (5) needs to be executed while the content of `buf` is `dataB`.

Due to the inherently asynchronous nature of OpenGL, the interesting case is call (4). Let's say that `dataA` has been stored in `buf` at this point in time, and the draw command for call (3) has been queued up for execution by the GPU. But we can't rely on the GPU having executed that draw command yet. So we can't store `dataB` in `buf` because the pending draw command has to be executed by the GPU while `dataA` is still stored in `buf`. But we can't return from the call before we consumed `dataB`.

There are various approaches for handling this situation. The brute force solution is to simply block the execution of call (4) until the GPU has finished executing the draw command from call (3). That will certainly work, but can have very bad performance implications. Because we wait until the GPU completed work before we submit new work, the GPU will likely go temporarily idle. This is often called a "bubble" in the pipeline, and is very undesirable. On top of that, the application is also blocked from doing useful work until the call returns.

The simplest way to work around this is for the driver to copy `dataB` in call (4), and later place this copy of the data in `buf`, after the GPU has completed the draw command from call (3), but before the draw command from call (5) is executed. The downside is that it involves additional data copying, but it's often well worth it to prevent the pipeline bubbles.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've updated the question, please check it again.

Comment: I found several articles saying that it will create pipeline bubbles, that's why I'm quite confused.

Comment: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-AsynchronousBufferTransfers.pdf   (Page 397)

Comment: You added the `glMapBuffer` case in the question. I don't know as much about that, but I figure it could be handled similarly. I think I explained the problem for `glBufferSubData`, and how it can be handled in the driver both with and without blocking. Are there any specific parts in my answer that are unclear?

Comment: But it says "When using glBufferSubData...Drivers have to avoid this problem by blocking the function until the desired data are not used anymore", according to your answer, it doesn't need to block.

Comment: Right. If a question is based on false assumptions, I think it's perfectly appropriate to correct them as part of an answer. There's a lot of false information on the internet. So just because somebody writes this, you shouldn't automatically assume that it's true.